# What's the difference between void() and void{}?

Tags: c++, c++11

Basically, I'd like to know why the compiler rejects `ptr2` declaration:

```
int main() {
    // this one works
    decltype(void())* ptr1;

    // this one does not
    decltype(void{})* ptr2;
}
```

Take a look at [this code](http://ideone.com/6IsZe9) if you think that `ptr1` is a function pointer:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
void f(T t) {
    cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
}

int main() {
    decltype(void())* ptr;
    f(ptr);
}
```

The output is `void f(T) [with T = void*]`.

Comment: What is `void{}` supposed to be?

Comment: @chris Same thing that `void()` is, whatever that might be.

Comment: "this one works" ... "this one does not" -- Looks like that's the difference.

Comment: @KeithThompson But why is there any difference at all?

Comment: @catscradle: I don't know C++ well enough to answer that. I wouldn't have expected `void{}` to be valid syntax -- and g++ seems to agree. The error message I get seems to indicate that it expects it to be a compound literal -- and it accepts it if I change `void` to `int`.

Comment: @jeffamaphone Why did you remove `c++` tag? I mean, `c++11` is still `c++`, right?..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[expr.type.conv]

> 2 The expression `T()`, where `T` is a *simple-type-specifier* or *typename-specifier* for a non-array complete object type or the (possibly *cv*-qualified) `void` type, creates a prvalue of the specified type, whose value is that produced by value-initializing (8.5) an object of type `T`; no initialization is done for the `void()` case. [...]

N.B. `void` **is** a *simple-type-specifier*.

> 3 Similarly, a *simple-type-specifier* or *typename-specifier* followed by a *braced-init-list* creates a temporary object of the specified type direct-list-initialized (8.5.4) with the specified *braced-init-list*, and its value is that temporary object as a prvalue.

Thanks to [Keith Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/827263/keith-thompson) for pointing out that a **temporary object** is created in /3, whereas a **value** is created in /2.

When we take a look at [basic.types]/5

> Incompletely-defined object types and the `void` types are incomplete types (3.9.1). Objects shall not be defined to have an incomplete type.

It now becomes clear that `void{}` is not allowed as it would create a (temporary) object. `void()` however "only" creates a (pr)value. I don't think there's a difference in the implementation (behaviour) for those two cases, but different language rules apply to them. One of those rules forbids creation of an object of type `void`, hence the error.

---

Ad `decltype(void())`: `decltype(e)` takes an expression `e`. In [dcl.type.simple]/4, the applicable definition of `decltype(e)` is:

> otherwise, `decltype(e)` is the type of `e`

(as `void()` yields a prvalue and is not an *id-expression*).

Therefore, `decltype(void())` yields `void`.

Comment: I have no clue what `void()` is good for (it's not an artefact from C, as function-style conversion aren't allowed there).

Comment: So, the standard doesn't say directly that it's legal, so it isn't? Did I get it right?

Comment: I was just playing with an idea of using trailing return type with `decltype(&T::f, void())` for SFINAE instead of `enable_if` and some `has_f` construct. It looks nicer to me...

Comment: @catscradle I didn't find anything *specific* that clearly says it's illegal. You could argue that direct-list-initialization would lead to value-initialization, which is only defined for objects. Also, `void` is an incomplete type.

Comment: @catscradle That is indeed a usage for `void()` (IIRC I even used it that way already). However, the same should be possible with `(void)0` and `void(0)`. Guess I'll add `void();` then to my list of no-ops ;)

Comment: `void{}` would create a temporary object of type `void`. There are no objects of type `void`, temporary or otherwise.

Comment: I guess another reason is to simply allow for `T f() { return T(); }` in class templates when `T` becomes `void` (another similar case is to allow for `->~T();` when `T` becomes a scalar type such as `int`). I would them to do the same for `T{}` but apparently not.

Comment: .. indeed, this was already brought up on std-discussion https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-discussion/_lmDsXpxabY , but I can't find an active issue for this on the wg21 list.